# regex - squeeze spaces and remove dots in the names

Tags: regex, perl

I'm working on cleaning up NAMES i.e remove the dots and spaces before the actual name starts.
Example - Below is the test file

```
$ cat names.txt
J.J. Scott
J. S. Joyce
RV. Bradley Carter
M. N. K. Brailey
$
```

I need the output as below

```
JJ Scott
JS Joyce
RV Bradley Carter
MNK Brailey
```

The below perl attempt is not working for all scenarios.

```
perl -ne ' s/\.//g; s/ //; print ' names.txt
```

Comment: The second substitution `s/ //;` is missing the global modifier and will just remove 1 space.

Comment: @TLP.. that will make Bradley Carter to BradleyCarter.. which should not be.

Comment: It will also make `M N K` into `MN K` which it should not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `perl` command that does it in singe substitution:

```sh
perl -pe 's/\.\h*(?=(?:[A-Z]\.)*\h+[A-Z])//g' file

JJ Scott
JS Joyce
RV Bradley Carter
MNK Brailey
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TlGHM9/1/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\.\h*`: Match a dot followed by 0 or more spaces or tabs
- `(?=(?:[A-Z]\.)*\h+[A-Z])`: Lookahead to assert that we have 0 or more abbreviations followed by a space and an uppercase letter

Answer (score 1):

You might use:

```
\G\p{Lu}+\K[.\h]+(?!\p{Lu}\p{Ll})
```

- `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, or at the start in this case
- `\p{Lu}+\K` Match 1+ uppercase chars and forget what is matched so far using `\K`
- `[.\h]+` Match 1+ times either a dot or horizontal whitespace char
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not

  - `\p{Lu}\p{Ll}` Match an uppercase char followed by a lowercase char
- `)` Close lookahead

In the replacement use an empty string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ym1Noc/1)

For example

```
perl -pe 's/\G\p{Lu}+\K[.\h]+(?!\p{Lu}\p{Ll})//g' names.txt
```

Output

```
JJ Scott
JS Joyce
RV Bradley Carter
MNK Brailey
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a negative lookahead.  The first regex removes dots.  The second and third regexes are identical and both remove the space from space-separated capital (upper-case) letters unless the second is followed by a lower-case letter. The triple-initial name requires a repeat; otherwise, you end up with `MN K Brailey`.  Using `-p` instead of `-n` avoids having to write `print` in the code.

```sh
perl -pe 's/\.//g; s/([A-Z]) ([A-Z])(?![a-z])/$1$2/g; s/([A-Z]) ([A-Z])(?![a-z])/$1$2/g' names.txt
```

Output:

```
JJ Scott
JS Joyce
RV Bradley Carter
MNK Brailey
```